# how to distinguish readable UTF-8 string from binary gibberish?

Tags: php, utf-8

By readable UTF, i mean anything that is a valid UTF-8, not (of course) that the user must have a font to read that string.
example of readable strings:

```
$readable_str0 = "Mary had a little lamb.";
$readable_str1 = "Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.";
$readable_str4 = "صِف خَلقَ خَودِ كَمِثلِ الشَمسِ إِذ بَزَغَت يَحظى الضَجيعُ بِها نَجلاءَ مِعطارِ";
$readable_str5 = "ཨ་ཡིག་དཀར་མཛེས་ལས་འཁྲུངས་ཤེས་བློའི་གཏེར༎"; //(Dzongkha)
$readable_str7 = "とりなくこゑす　ゆめさませ　みよあけわたる";
$readable_str8 = "TWFyeSBoYWQgYSBsaXR0bGUgbGFtYi4=";
```

not readable strings:

```
$not_readable_str0 = "�M,�T�HLQHT��,)�IU�I�M�";
$not_readable_str1 = "9��Příšerně žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy."
// this has some odd characters at the beginning so should count as unreadable
// it was result of gzdeflate of readable str 1
$not_readable_str4 = "ŹĎ5ůĹńŁV»×~1xâţöÚkkąő«¶’ŢáJ";
//some random selection from gif file
```

Comment: You can't. What you call *binary gibberish* is still valid UTF-8. So instead of trying to *distinguish* tackle the problem at its root: fix the origin of the gibberish (broken database, encoding, ...) so that you don't end up with such code which requires *distinguishing*.

Comment: Yes We Can! - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723562/how-to-detect-malformed-utf-8-string-in-php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kind of dirty hack that most likely will fail in some cases:

```
$str2 = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $str);
```

and compare lenghts of $str and $str2.

Comment: That is it will give false positives or false negatives or both ?

Comment: This will try to ignore invalid byte sequences (as there can be such in utf-8 strings). Read it as from: utf-8 string to: utf-8 -invalid chars (or sequences) string. So if new string has different length this means there were removals and if there were removals it (first string) consists of invalid chars so it's not valid utf-8. Thus when compassion yelds false it means that first string is gibberish. It would be cool however if somebody with better utf understanding than me could confirm all of this that I'm talking about :)

Answer (score 3):

mb_check_encoding as suggested by another user, seems to be the way. At least, the easiest way in PHP.

I've actually done a lot of this before in C++! There, there is no mb_check_encoding function, I had to write my own.

**Don't use this code in PHP, it's just for curiosity's sake** ;) Use mb_check_encoding.

Also, this "What you call binary gibberish is still valid UTF-8" by another user, is TOTALLY WRONG. You CAN CHECK UTF-8 with a HIGH DEGREE OF ACCURACY. Assuming of course that it's not a tiny string like 4 bytes, and that it has a lot of "non-ascii" chars. UTF-8 has a specific and "hard to accidentally get right" pattern.

This code also checks for "non-shortest form" UTF-8, which is a security problem. "non-shortest form" UTF-8, can lead to a situation where one program that is meant to filter out bad commands, actually lets them through, perhaps leading to SQL injection holes.

No idea how PHP handles non-shortest form UTF-8 though ;) Best to check it yourself if it worries you.

```
long VerifyUTF8(u8* source, u8* sourceEnd) {
    while (source < sourceEnd) {
        u8 c = *source++;
        if (c >= 0x80) {
            u8* PrevPos = source - 1;
            source = LegalUTF8_(c, source);
            if ( source > sourceEnd or !source ) {
                return sourceEnd - PrevPos;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


// returns 0 if it fails! source point to the 2nd byte of the UTF8!
u8* LegalUTF8_(u8 FirstChar, u8* source) {
    if (FirstChar < 0xC2 or FirstChar > 0xF4) {
        return 0; // dissallows ASCII! No point calling this on ASCII!
    }
    u32 ch = FirstChar;
    u32 offset;
    u8 a = *source++;
    switch (FirstChar) {    /* no fall-through in this inner switch */
        case 0xE0: if (a < 0xA0) return 0; break;
        case 0xF0: if (a < 0x90) return 0; break;
        case 0xF4: if (a > 0x8F) return 0; break;
    }

    if (ch <= 0xDF) {
        offset = 0x00003080;
        goto case2;
    } else if (ch <= 0xEF) {
        offset = 0x000E2080;
        goto case3;
    } else { // case 4
        offset = 0x03C82080;
    }

    ch <<= 6; ch += a;
    if (a < 0x80 or a > 0xBF) {
        return 0;
    }
    a = *source++;

    case3:; ch <<= 6; ch += a;
    if (a < 0x80 or a > 0xBF) {
        return 0;
    }
    a = *source++;

    case2:; ch <<= 6; ch += a;
    if (a < 0x80 or a > 0xBF) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (UniValid(ch-offset)) {
        return source;
    }
    return 0;
}


bool UniValid( u32 c ) { // negative c looks like > 2 billion, which is going to return false!
    if ( c < 0xD800 ) { // common case first
        return true;
    } else if ( c <= 0x0010FFFF and c > 0xDFFF and c != 0xFFFF and c != 0xFFFE ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```