# XML not well formed due to long UTF characters

Tags: php, xml, character-encoding, iconv

Ok, I hope somebody can help because I haven't been able to find a solution for this.

In the database, customers managed to import or otherwise add character data from a different character set such as:

```
  <E2><80><99>
```

I believe this is UTF-16.

The XML output of my script is throwing errors due to this data (which pulls strings, such as a "description" field, from the database and builds an XML file).

XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Line Number 20, Column 50.

There's some other hex that's longer, like <80><99> (just an example, im not sure if this is an actual character).

How can I make my XML file valid, and either downscale the character set or get it to use UTF-32 like so:

```
  AddType "application/xml; charset=UTF-32" xml  (in .htaccess file along with filesmatch .xml)


  <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-32' ?>   (placed in head of xml file)
```

Comment: `0xe2 0x80 0x99` is UTF-8 for 'RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK' (U+2019), I think your problem lies elsewhere. Could you show us the first few lines of xml?

Comment: Where are you seeing these errors? Do you have a example URL? What is Line Number 20? What is at Column 50?

Comment: Here's an example:


     XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
     Location: http://x.x.x.x/xml/hal-default.xml
     Line Number 20, Column 50:   <description>The    Hangmans Creek Ranch is a 190 (the special char is right here after "190") acre ranch



Looking at this through a hex editor:



0001140 3931 b130 6120 7263 2065 6172 636e 2068
          1   9   0   1  sp   a   c   r   e  sp   r   a   n   c   h  sp



Does that clarify anything?

Comment: Which program does give you that error? Is it PHP? If so, what is the related PHP code?

Comment: This error happens when the .xml file is viewed in the browser (FireFox 10 in my case), but also other browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever it is: UTF-8, -16 or -32 - If you choose some other encoding with your output, you must - if it differs - re-encode your input for output first.

You clearly state in your question that you don't know what the input encoding is exactly. That's a point you need to get clear straight because encoding is meta-information. You need to know it properly to process strings. From what you shared, it looks like the input is UTF-8 encoded. You should verify that ([How to detect malformed utf-8 string in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723562/how-to-detect-malformed-utf-8-string-in-php)).

Next thing is, that malformed must not mean an encoding problem (but it can). As long as you don't share the source of the problem (ideally next to text-form as well [with a hex-dump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057572/how-can-i-get-a-hex-dump-of-a-string-in-php)), there is not much advice that can be given for the current information I'd say.

Comment: Here's an example:


     XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
     Location: http://x.x.x.x/xml/hal-default.xml
     Line Number 20, Column 50:   <description>The    Hangmans Creek Ranch is a 190 (the special char is right here after "190") acre ranch



Looking at this through a hex editor:



0001140 3931 b130 6120 7263 2065 6172 636e 2068
          1   9   0   1  sp   a   c   r   e  sp   r   a   n   c   h  sp



Does that clarify anything?